# Button border is not appearing using drawable in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using this code for adding a border to my button layout but no change is appearing in the button.

button_bg.xml(drawable)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="14dp"
        />
    <solid
        android:color="#fff"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="3px"
        android:color="#000"
        />
</shape>
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="@string/category_name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried your code, that is working perfectly fine

Comment: you are testing the change or real device? In my case I have tested on both and working perfect on real and emulator as well

Comment: It appears in layout xml but when I run this code It doesn't work.

Comment: I am using this button as an item in a recycler view

Comment: then please add the code you are using in recycler view

Comment: Oh yes, the problem was in my recycler view. I was overriding the background colour. Problem is solved!!

Comment: :) great then..